# SharedPreferences overwrite value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, spinner

I am making an application in which i am using a `Spinner`, `EditText` and a `Button` when user fill that text and click that `Button` the text will be shown in `Spinner` and my problem is i do all the stuff but when i add the data to `Spinner` it override the previous data and the previous data won't showed up

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Spinner spinner1;
    Button add;
    EditText subject;
    ArrayAdapter btArrayAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(btArrayAdapter);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                                       int position, long id) {
                String item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                // Showing selected spinner item
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Selected Subject : " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        SharedPreferences sharedPref =getSharedPreferences("Info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("Spinner_name",subject.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void btnClick(View view)
    {
        String content;
        content = subject.getText().toString();
        btArrayAdapter.add(content);
         btArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        btArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    }
}
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.helloworld/com.example.helloworld.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                             at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:153)
>                                                                             at com.example.helloworld.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:30)
>                                                                             at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>                                                                             at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
>                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
>                                                                             at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                             at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
>                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: in your title, do you mean _Override_ or _Overwrite_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the functionality by keeping single `ArrayAdapter` and update it on button click. Also as Code-Apprentice said you can save the data in form of `Set<String>` inside preference `onDestory`.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /* Views */
    Spinner spinner;
    Button add;
    EditText subject;

    /* Adapter */
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    /* Preference */
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* initializing views */
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        /* Get spinner data from preference */
        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("Info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Set<String> savedStringSet = sharedPref.getStringSet("SpinnerData", null);
        if (savedStringSet != null) {
            list = new ArrayList<>(savedStringSet);
        }

        /* Setting up spinner */
        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                list.toArray(new String[list.size()]));
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                                       int position, long id) {
                String item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                // Showing selected spinner item
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Selected Subject : " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        /* save list in shared preference */
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putStringSet("SpinnerData", new HashSet<String>(list));
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void btnClick(View view) {
        String content = subject.getText().toString();      // get user entered text.

        /* update spinner */
        list.add(content);          // add to data list..
        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        /* set updated spinner */
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
}
```

**Note:** You might need to put some validations, inside `btnClick` method, for edit text values in case you don't want to save empty string on `""` button click.

Comment: when i run this code the application crashes i edit my question see the error

Comment: updated answer. it was due to 'SharedPreference` was initialised in class instance. now it should work.

Comment: Hey After adding data to spinner when i close the application and reopen it..it wont open its crashes

Comment: What does stack trace says?

Comment: i am running app in emulator when i run the app through android studio it launches and prevs data is also there but when i add new data and close the application and again try to lauch it but it crashes

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH dude its working charm on real device

Answer (score 1):

```
editor.putString("Spinner_name",subject.getText().toString());
```

Each time you do this the old string is overwritten.

First, you should declare the ArrayAdapter as a class field. Then in onClick(), you need to add each String to the ArrayAdapter. Finally in onDestroy() you can save all the strings to SharedPreferences.

```
btArrayAdapter.add(content);
btArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
btArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Here you add the string correctly but then you immediately throw away the adapter and create a new one. Don't do that. You should only initialize the adapter once in onCreate().

```
editor.putString("Spinner_name",subject.getText().toString());
```

This only saves the most recent string. It also overwrites the previous one. You need to get all the strings from the adapter then save them as a string set.

Comment: Can you post an answer how  to do that

Comment: @FaizMir You should be able to figure it out from what I wrote here.

Comment: But i tried writing string on array adapter but when i close the application and start it again nothing shows up in the spinner

Comment: @FaizMir Being new to Android is exactly why you should take the time to fill some research and figure it out yourself. I suggest you become familiar with the Android Developer documentat.

Comment: @FaizMir You can save the list of strings before your app quits  in onDestroy().

Comment: I have to put that list in on destroy method  ryt?

Comment: okay i got it then if i  close and open my application again the item will show up?

Comment: See My edited question i have done  is this correct ?

Comment: @FaizMir What happens when you run it?

Comment: when i close the application and open it again nothing shows up in the spinner

Comment: @FaizMir Then it isn't correct. You don't have to ask.

Comment: can u please tell me where i am going wrong on that code

Comment: i remove that from on click and put it on create

Comment: the thing is when i add text to spinner one by one it get added perfectly and shows up like dropdown menu but when i close the application and open it again the text i have added its gone the i have to add it again

Comment: I dont know How to do that

Comment: @FaizMir that's what google is for. Also check the Android Documentation for ArrayAdapter and SharedPreferences.